# How does one find the percentiles for a variable by a descriptor variable in Stata?

Tags: stata, percentile

I'm trying to find the 10th and 90th percentiles for income by state in my dataset. I know the basic code to find the percentiles for the entire dataset would be as follows:

```
centile (medhhinc_2019), centile (10 90)
```

How can I get these by each state instead of the entire dataset?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this ended up being quite simple.

```
tabstat medhhinc_2019, statistics(p10 p90) by(state)
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use `astile ffd=medhhinc_2019,nq(10)`,which can divide medhhinc into ten groups according to precentiles

Comment: Your code does something different and does not address the question of doing calculations separately by state.

Comment: I was looking to get the 10th and 90th percentiles for each state, and I was able to do so using that line of code.  I'll remove the "sd" and "iqr", but I was grabbing those in addition to the other statistics.  Thanks though.